# How can I check length of the uI, Cypress test is yielding only 1

Tags: javascript, cypress

The below(highlight in green) is a dropdown, it has about 10 options. When I try `cy.get(element)` it yields only 1.

Structure.

[image]

Console SC

[image]

I am trying to use something like

```js
cy.get(element) .should('have.length', '9')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<ul>` is parent of the 10 `<li>` underneath.

If you select `ul`, use `children()` to count the options.

```js
cy.get('ul[data-cy="offerBreakUpJobTitleAndIdFilterComboboxOptions"]')
  .children('li')
  .should('have.length', '10')
```

I notice also you have multiple elements using the testing id of

```js
data-cy="offerBreakUpJobTitleAndIdFilterComboboxOptions"
```

This might give you trouble selecting the element you want.

Comment: Its giving length of 6.

Comment: It works for me - replicated from your screenshot (actually you have 10 not 9).

Comment: You also have a `.click()` in the second screenshot, so there is something else going on that's not given in in the question. What's the full test look like?

Comment: ok so this one worked, 
`cy.get('[data-cy="offerBreakUpJobTitleAndIdFilterComboboxButton"]').click()
 cy.get('ul[data-cy="offerBreakUpJobTitleAndIdFilterComboboxOptions"]')
.children().should('have.length', '9')`

Thanks.

Comment: I have to follow up question since I want to verify content in each of the li I am using the below command and this is getting my work done, wanted to know if there is a better way.

`cy.get('ul[data-cy="offerBreakUpJobTitleAndIdFilterComboboxOptions"]')
 .children()
 .first()
 .should('have.text', 'Tittle 1')
 .next()
 .should('have.text', 'Tittle 2')`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. You have to get the `li` selector to get the length as 9.

```js
cy.get('li[data-cy*="offerBreakUpJobTitle"]').should('have.length', 9)
```

If you have just one list on the webpage, you can also do like this:

```js
cy.get('li').should('have.length', 9)
```